# Scraping Data (table) from ESPN fantasy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a table from this website: https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1589782588 in python however I'm having trouble actually grabbing data. In the developer console I tried out

```
let players = document.getElementsByClassName("AnchorLink link clr-link pointer")
players[0].text
```

And I was able to output the players' names. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you have tried doing using Python

Answer (score 2):

They actually loads data using JavaScript, so I don't think you can use BeautifulSoup to scrape data. Alternatively, you can use [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for that, you haven't provided any code so, do your own research about selenium about how to scrape data.  You can execute JavaScript as well using selenium, you can take help from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python) to learn about how to run JavaScript.

If you look as the network log page of the developer tool then you may find URL that loads data of player which you want but it require a bit of more effort.